# how to use door_handle_detector to detect door handle

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
how to use door_handle_detector (http://www.ros.org/wiki/door_handle_detector) to detect a door or a handle?

i plugin kinect in the PC,and try this command in terminal:

```
roslaunch door_handle_detector door_closed_40.launch
```

(there are lots of ***.lauch ,

```
bag_detector.launch
door_closed_39.launch
door_closed_40.launch
door_closed_alex.launch
……
```

i don't konw which one to use ,so i random select one to see what result will be)

BUT,i get ERROR as follows:

**FATAL] [1318863811.703771799]: Failed to open file: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_doors/door_handle_detector/test/door_closed_40.bag (Error opening file: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_doors/door_handle_detector/test/door_closed_40.bag)
[rosplay-6] process has died [pid 21335, exit code 1].
log files: /home/mochen/.ros/log/2d2db2aa-f8d1-11e0-8185-00218545f6b8/rosplay-6*.log**

-------------------------ths to David , added ------------------------------
(just use an  kinect to detect door or handle,without other camera sensor or laser)

```
roslaunch door_handle_detector door_handle_detector_vision.xml
```

get an error:

```
core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [stereo_image_proc/stereoproc]:
Cannot locate node of type     [stereoproc] in package [stereo_image_proc]
```

the program doesn't crash down,it still running,some info in terminal as follows:
**process[handle_detector_vision-2]: started with pid [2447]
(0): /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_doors/door_handle_detector/bin/handle_detector_vision
(1): stereo:=narrow_stereo
(2): __name:=handle_detector_vision
(3): __log:=/home/myname/.ros/log/ebf7adc4-f923-11e0-8cd6-00218545f6b8/handle_detector_vision-2.log
[ INFO] [1318900069.233772913]: Loading cascade classifier: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_doors/door_handle_detector/data/handles_data.xml**

but wait for a long long time,it is still loading the /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_doors/door_handle_detector/data/handles_data.xml .

so waht is the problem now,how to solve it?ths!

---------------------------------------------added end------------------------------------------

use Kinect,ubuntu 11.04 ,ROS version is diamondback,PCL1.2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11574/how-to-use-door_handle_detector-to-detect-door-handle/) by [emerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/970/emerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-10-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-10-17**:
A more detailed description of what you tried and what failed would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch file you are using is in the "test" folder, and does not appear to be up to date. It looks like its using the old rosbag commands for playing test data. If you want to use that test data, you should use something like this

`<node pkg="rosbag" type="rosplay" name="rosplay" args="-r 0.5 -b 100 $(find door_handle_detector)/test/door_closed_daniel.bag"/>`

However, if you want a live door detection, try one of the launch files from the launch directory, like door_hand_detector_vision.xml

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/970/emerson/) on 2011-10-18**:
hi David,thanks .but now ,i meet another problem when roslaunch door_handle_detector door_handle_detector_vision.xml,ERROR :core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [stereo_image_proc/stereoproc]: Cannot locate node of type [stereoproc] in package [stereo_image_proc]